# Linq to Entities using Lambda Expressions and multiple where conditions

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am trying to select a list of objects at the end of a fairly long chain of joins/selects using Linq to Entities written as Lambda Expressions... Here is what I have currently the following two statements.

```
    var formDefId = _unitOfWork.AsQueryableFor<FormTrack>()
        .Where(x => x.FormTrackId == formTrackId)
        .Select(x => x.FormDefId).First();

    var rules = _unitOfWork.AsQueryableFor<FormTrack>()
        .Where(x => x.FormTrackId == formTrackId)
        .Select(x => x.FormDef)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Events
            .Where(y => y.EventTypeId == 7))
        .Select(x => x.RuleGroup)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Rules)
        .SelectMany(x => x.RuleFormXmls
            .Where(y => y.FormDefId == formDefId));
```

What I would like to do, is combine the two queries, and use the FormDefId returned by

```
.Select(x => x.FormDef)
```

in the final where clause instead of having to use the formDefId from a separate query.

Is this something that is possible?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier to write this using query syntax.. Each `from` in query syntax corresponds to a `SelectMany` in lambda syntax. This allows you to have all the variables in scope.

```
var rules = 
  from ft in _unitOfWork.AsQueryableFor<FormTrack>()
  from e in ft.FormDef.Events
  from r in e.RuleGroup.Rules
  from x in r.RuleFormXmls
  where ft.FormTrackId == formTrackId
  where e.EventTypeId == 7
  where x.FormDefId == ft.FormDefId
  select x
```